# Unable to delete a user: user test is currently used by process xxx

Tags: linux, users, accounts

I'm trying to delete a user:

```
pgrep -u test
ps -fp $(pgrep -u test)
killall -KILL -u test
userdel -r test
```

But the last command always returns

```
userdel: user test is currently used by process xxx
```

where `xxx` is always different.

Comment: What does `ps aux | grep xxx` show, if anything?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, it shows that process.

Comment: And what is the process?